# How can I show the video stream from the server in pyqt with the client?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pyqt, qpixmap

Below codes work fine as **server-client** but video comes in **opencv** generated window. I want the video to be inside a **PyQt** window. How can I do it?

Note:With QPixmap, I could normally view the live stream video on my own computer in pyqt, but I didn't do this with the server-client structure.

```
#server.py    

import socket, cv2, pickle,struct,imutils

# Socket Create
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name  = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print('HOST IP:',host_ip)
port = 9999
socket_address = (host_ip,port)

# Socket Bind
server_socket.bind(socket_address)

# Socket Listen
server_socket.listen(5)


# Socket Accept
while True:
    client_socket,addr = server_socket.accept()
    print('GOT CONNECTION FROM:',addr)
    if client_socket:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        
        while(vid.isOpened()):
            img,frame = vid.read()
            frame = imutils.resize(frame,width=320)
            a = pickle.dumps(frame)
            message = struct.pack("Q",len(a))+a
            client_socket.sendall(message)
            
            cv2.imshow('TRANSMITTING VIDEO',frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key ==ord('q'):
                client_socket.close()
```

```
#client.py
import socket,cv2, pickle,struct

# create socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name  = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
port = 9999
client_socket.connect((host_ip,port)) # a tuple
data = b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
while True:
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        packet = client_socket.recv(4*1024) # 4K
        if not packet: break
        data+=packet
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("Q",packed_msg_size)[0]
    
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += client_socket.recv(4*1024)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data  = data[msg_size:]
    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
    cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key  == ord('q'):
        break
client_socket.close()
```

Comment: remove the imshow, use Qt methods to show `frame` however Qt needs that shown. `frame` is a numpy array. you are not the first to want numpy arrays shown in Qt. -- please review [mre]. all that sockets stuff has no place in a MRE about how to show numpy arrays in a Qt GUI. you haven't even used Qt in your code! you should start with that.

Comment: You need to use QThread and signal/slots to achieve your purpose, basically create a new QThread that receives the frame, emit it using the signal and connect that signal to appropriate slot.. and there you have it without blocking the UI Event Loop.. the frame received in function and you can further perform operation on it.. for further info search opencv and pyqt in google and you'll find enough information there